# Changing button design while holding it in C# windows application form

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to design a button in which when I hold it it will change the style of a button. Like the current button-style is square with no border but when I hold it by mouse it will change the style of a button from square to round or 3d square but when I leave that button it will change back to my original style

**This is what I tried:**

```
 private void btnfeeder2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
            {
                Button btnfeeder2 = sender as Button;
                if (btnfeeder2 != null)
                {
                btnfeeder2.FlatStyle = (btnfeeder2.FlatStyle == FlatStyle.Standard) ? FlatStyle.System : FlatStyle.Standard;
                }
            }
```

**as result:**
it does change the button style but not by holding it but by pressing it and it stays even if I leave the button. I have to click the button again to go back to my original style.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For verification, I changed the default back color to red.

```
    private void btnfeeder2_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        
            btnfeeder2.FlatStyle = (btnfeeder2.FlatStyle == FlatStyle.Standard) ? FlatStyle.System : FlatStyle.Standard;
            btnfeeder2.BackColor = Color.White;
      
    }
    
    private void btnfeeder2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
      
            btnfeeder2.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
            btnfeeder2.BackColor = Color.Red;
        
    }
```

Comment: Why are you Invoking? From the UI Thread. Please, remove that invocation stuff, someone may thing you can actually do that.

Comment: there is no need of invoke. that thing is unnecessary.